# why does partitioning+bucketing taking longer than querying from normal table?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase, apache-pig

my data looks like following:

```
Wban Number, YearMonthDay, Time, Hourly Precip
03011,20060301,0050,0
```

now this file has more than 1 million+ rows. So I created a table with both partitions(on wbannumber) and buckets( on yearmonthday):

```
create table hpd_bkt
(
YearMonthDay INT,
Time INT, 
HourlyPrecip float
)
partitioned by (wbannum int)
clustered by (yearmonthday) sorted by (yearmonthday) into 31 buckets
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

then:

```
insert overwrite table hpd_bkt partition(wbannum)
Select  yearmonthday,time,hourlyprecip,wbannum from hpd;
```

Now I used following query to get distinct wbannumbers ( for partition+bucket table):

```
select count(distinct wbannum) from hpd_bkt;
```

It took total of 103 seconds to process this ( 13 sec CPU time)

But when querying the same from normal data table, it takes 21 seconds in total ( 8 sec CPU time)

Can any one explain, what i might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is partitioning with bucketing might have resulted in lots of smaller files. Ideally your file sizes should be at-least of block size to get good performance.

Watch the number of mappers scheduled in both the cases. In partitioning & bucketing case you might notice more number of mappers each for smaller data-set.

Comment: So for partitioning and bucketing, the initial data load will take time, is it?

Comment: yes its a data transformation (with full copy) performed to re-arrange data.